# Error "No se puede cargar el archivo <ruta_del_archivo> porque la ejecución de scripts está deshabilitada en este sistema" al hacer ng serve

Tags: angular, npm

Esto es lo que me sale en mi Visual Studio Code. Es cuando hago `ng serve`

```
ng : No se puede cargar el archivo C:\Users\JAVIER\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 porque la ejecución de scripts está deshabilitada en este sistema. Para 
obtener más información, consulta el tema about_Execution_Policies en https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ ng serve --open
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

[image: something]

Answer (score 3):

Abrir powershell como Administrador! y ejecutar el comando

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

luego reiniciar sistema Asi podras ejecutar el script

[otros comandos útiles para este problema](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6)

Deberia mostrarte luego

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy
    Unrestricted
```

Comment: si mi sistema lo tiene por seguridad, y lo deshabilito que sucede?

Answer (score 1):

También puedes probar borra el archivo de la siguiente ruta C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1

Comment: Me funciono gracias, yo estaba intentando con ng g m name_modulo, borre el archivo que comenta, y funciono la creación del modulo.

Answer (score 0):

La directiva de ejecución de PowerShell es una característica de seguridad que controla las condiciones en las que PowerShell carga archivos de configuración y ejecuta scripts. Esta característica ayuda a evitar la ejecución de scripts malintencionados.

Para cambiar la política de ejecución de PowerShell en su computadora con Windows, use el Set-ExecutionPolicy

y ejecutar el comando

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Answer (score 0):

Paso a paso:

1. Abrir CMD o PowerShell como Administrador - "Ejecutar como administrador"
2. Pegar el siguiente comando `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
3. Reiniciar CMD o PowerShell
4. `ng new nameApp`